# Alternativa de localstorage para ver modificacion en todos los dispositivos

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una página web y en una de sus hojas "armar.html" he creado un formulario, de tal manera que el director del coro pueda seleccionar los cantos, es decir, por ejemplo el canto de elevación y en la lista desplegable elige por ejemplo "Señor mio y Dios mio", esta elección se guarda en una variable en javascript y a su vez alimenta el campo src de un iframe para traer la letra y los acordes del canto seleccionado. El inconveniente es que estoy usando el "localStorage" por tanto si yo lo hago desde el pc, los cambio se ven sólo en el pc y no en los demás dispositivos, ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el cambio de la variable se actualice en todos los dispositivos, y quede fija hasta que el director decida entrar y modificar nuevamente.

Codigo del formulario para seleccionar el canto.

```
<label class="col-3" for="CDPenitencial">Penitencial</label>
                  <select class="col-7" id="penitencial">
                    <option selected=""></option>
                    <option value="Cantos/PE0005.html">Señor Ten Piedad (Tres Voces)</option>
                    <option value="Cantos/PE0006.html">Seeeñor, Ten Piedad (Cristo Ten Piedad, Ten Piedad)</option>
                    <option value="Cantos/PE0009.html">Señor, Señor Ten Piedad, (Re)</option>
                    <option value="Cantos/PE00010.html">Señor, Señor, Ten Piedad (Contestación)</option>
                    <option value="Cantos/PE00012.html">Ten Piedad Soy Pecador</option>
                    
                  </select>
```

Código de la función de javascript que almacena la elección del canto.

```
function capturarp() {
  var Penitencialform = document.getElementById("penitencial").value;
  console.log(Penitencialform);
  localStorage.setItem('penitencialSeleccionado', Penitencialform);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let penitencialSeleccionado = localStorage.getItem('penitencialSeleccionado');
  let iframe = document.querySelector("#penitencial iframe");
  if (penitencialSeleccionado)
    iframe.src = penitencialSeleccionado;
});
```

Código que del OTRO html que actualiza el valor del src con el valor del canto seleccionado.

```
<section id="penitencial" class="penitencial">
    <h1 class="container">Penitencial</h1>
    <iframe src="" class="encuentro"></iframe>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let penitencialSeleccionado = localStorage.getItem('penitencialSeleccionado');
  let iframe = document.querySelector("#penitencial iframe");
  if (penitencialSeleccionado)
    iframe.src = penitencialSeleccionado;
});
</script>
```

Muchas Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Necesitas persistir esa información en una Base da Datos. Los datos almacenados en localstorage son guardados en la sesión del navegador, por lo que solamente podrán visualizarse desde el dispositivo y el navegador desde donde se hayan almacenado por lo que cada combinación de ordenador + navegador tiene los suyos propios, no pudiendo ver los cambios que le hagas desde fuera.

Comment: Miguel y existe manera que me puedas colaborar, soy nuevo en este tema y no sé como hacerlo. :(

Comment: Sumando a la respuesta de arriba, necesitarías crear un servicio intermediario entre tu Frontend y la Base de Datos, podrías construirlo en distintos lenguajes Backend como Java, Python, .Net, etc... Pero en este caso en particular te recomendaría PHP ya que se adaptaría fácilmente a la estructura que tiene tu proyecto actualmente (JavaScript + HTML) y hay muchos tutoriales en internet muy básicos sobre como utilizar PHP + MySQL (la Base de Datos con la que casi siempre va de la mano PHP).

Comment: Como ya has entendido, la información guardada en LocalStorage se queda sólo en ese dispositivo. Incluso si tú mismo accedes desde otro dispositivo no tendrás la información, de modo que la forma de persistir es mediante una base de datos u otras herramientas como  Firebase, etc. El contenido estará en un solo sitio y todos podrán acceder a él. Esto tiene más ventajas, como guardar por ejemplo lo que se cantó el día tal, o sacar estadísticas del tipo: cuántas veces se cantó tal canto, o cuál es el canto más usado en el año tal, etc. O que el director ponga el programa de cantos de todo el mes.

Comment: Gracias A. Cedano, pregunta mediante indexedDB lo podría solucionar?.

Comment: @A.Cedano, esta pregunta es justo para ti. :D. Juan Sebastián: Con las etiquetas actuales no hay manera de responder esta pregunta. Si incluyes alguna backend que sepas usar o esté soportada en los servidores, se podría ir armando una idea, aunque lo ideal es que investigues por tu cuenta y cuando ya vayas encaminado vengas con las dudas que te vayan surgiendo.

Comment: Nooop, `IndexDB` es algo más avanzado que LocalStorage, pero que también funciona **del lado del cliente**. Para este caso necesitas algo que esté disponible para **todos** los clientes que vayan a acceder. La solución habitual es una base de datos remota a la cual puedes acceder desde cualquier parte: un PC, un móvil, una tablet, estés donde estés. El modo de acceso no importa, puedes programar una aplicación en PHP, o en otro lenguaje, o una API o una aplicación móvil de Andorid o de Apple o lo que sea, según tus conocimientos y necesidades.

Comment: Y, vas a necesitar también conocimientos de SQL, para diseñar la base de datos que contendrá la información... En resumen, necesitas al menos tres herramientas: conocer algún lenguaje de programación para todo lo que es el código de servidor (PHP es el más habitual) y SQL para la base de datos. Y puede que también Javascript para manejar la parte del código en el cliente (el navegador en este caso). Ahora bien, con esas tres herramientas podrás resolver cualquier problema por complejo que sea.

Comment: Como ya te comenta @jachguate cualquier bloqueo o problema basado en código concreto aquí te ayudaremos a resolverlo, pero te toca a ti elegir con qué herramientas quieres trabajar.

Comment: Te la haré fácil. Usa https://firebase.google.com/ ejemplos vas a encontrar por montones. Este es un servicio que al nivel que lo vas a usar tu te saldrá gratis. Con el podrás hacer que el Director cambie una canción y a todos los que tengan abierta la aplicación les cambie el valor automáticamente, además que te guardará el último seleccionado y me parece que te va a requerir menos conocimientos que las solución que ya te han mencionado. Además acá mismo te podemos ayudar, pero tu pregunta tiene que está orientada a esa tecnología (o a la que elijas)

Comment: Perfecto, empezaré a usar bases de Datos con MYSQL en el servidor 000Webhost, mil gracias por su ayuda, como puedo darle el chulito a la pregunta (CHECK)